# I'm getting Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted ... on dispatch action in formik onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

Im trying to set a value to a varible when a get success after a response from formik submit, this variable is being used to control a success message component

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
const [recovered, setRecovered] = React.useState(false);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await dispatch(recoveryPassword(values.email))


    setLoading(false);

    if (response.status === 200) {
        setRecovered(true)
    }
}

<Formik
    validateOnChange={false}
    initialValues={{ email: '' }}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
    {({
        handleSubmit,
    }) => (
            <form className="forgot-password__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field
                    label="Seu email"
                    color={mainColor}
                    name="email"
                    component={TextInput}
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 0
                    }}
                />

                <div className="forgot-password__form-button">
                    <Button
                        theme="primary"
                        title="Recuperar senha"
                        weight="normal"
                        textcolor={WHITE}
                        background-color={mainColor}
                        type="submit"
                        loading={loading}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        )}
</Formik>
```

actions.js

```
export const recoveryPassword = (email) => async dispatch => {

  return post('/users/forgot-password', { email }).then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: ACTION_TYPE.RECOVERED, payload: response.data });

    return response;
  }).catch((error) => {
    dispatch({ type: ACTION_TYPE.RECOVERY_FAILED, payload: error.data });
    if (error.data.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE.SHOW_NOTIFICATION, payload: {
          variant: 'error',
          notificationMessage: error.data.message
        }
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE.SHOW_NOTIFICATION, payload: {
          variant: 'error',
          notificationMessage: 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar solicitar o reset de senha'
        }
      });
    }

    return error;
  });
};
```

Formik `onSubmit` calls `handlesSubmit`. When the code reaches `setLoading(false)` and then `setRecovered(true)`, it warns:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
>   cleanup function.

`loading` variable (which `setLoading` is modifying), is being modified. But `recovered` (by `setRecovered`) is not

Comment: could you give a complete code snippet for this? the warning is telling that you have an async function that is needed to be cleaned up before unmounting the component.

Comment: I've add my Formik wrapper . the async function handleSubmit

Comment: In this line: "const response = await dispatch(recoveryPassword(values.email))",  why did you await the dispatch? are you sure this is a promise? i'm asking this because i don''t  know the libraries you use like redux-thunk, etc..

Comment: Actually, i want to await recoveryPassword() for handling loading e content after response. I'll write my action too

Comment: Did you test some actions with this pattern? Did it work? I think the issue is in that line I just pointed out.

Comment: Yes, action are being dispatched normally